# android can create event not editable in calendar?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I need help with an android  application I want to create ad event in calendar (NOT GOOGLE CALENDAR BUT SIMPLY CALENDAR) not editable.

Now I use this code fro create event and calendar:

```
    pushAppointmentsToCalender(this, "TITLE", "DESCRIPTION", "CITY", 1, MYDATE, false, false);

public static long pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDate, boolean needReminder, boolean needMailService) {

        String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
        eventValues.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        eventValues.put("calendar_id", 2); // id, We need to choose from
                                            // our mobile for primary
                                            // its 1
        eventValues.put("title", title);

        eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);
        eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);



        long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr


        eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
        eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);
        eventValues.put("guestsCanModify", 0);

        eventValues.put("eventStatus", status); // This information is




        Uri eventUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

  return eventID;

    }
```

This code works but if i open my calendar i can modify the event.

There is a property of event like: `eventIsEditable = False`?

Comment: That would be perfect for spamming one's calendar. I hope it is not possible.

Comment: Calendar events entered from facebook are not editable. Obviously from you authorize an application to insert events.

How can I insert code to an event can not be changed?

Answer (score 0):

From android's Calendar provider [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#events)

These are all the fields an even can have

- CALENDAR_ID  The _ID of the calendar the event belongs to.
- ORGANIZER    Email of the organizer (owner) of the event.
- TITLE    The title of the event.
- EVENT_LOCATION   Where the event takes place.
- DESCRIPTION  The description of the event.
- DTSTART  The time the event starts in UTC milliseconds since the epoch.
- DTEND    The time the event ends in UTC milliseconds since the epoch.
- EVENT_TIMEZONE   The time zone for the event.
- EVENT_END_TIMEZONE   The time zone for the end time of the event.
- DURATION The duration of the event in RFC5545 format. For example, a value of "PT1H" states that the event should last one hour, and a value of "P2W" indicates a duration of 2 weeks.
- ALL_DAY  A value of 1 indicates this event occupies the entire day, as defined by the local time zone. A value of 0 indicates it is a regular event that may start and end at any time during a day.
- RRULE    The recurrence rule for the event format. For example, "FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;WKST=SU". You can find more examples here.
  RDATE   The recurrence dates for the event. You typically use RDATE in conjunction with RRULE to define an aggregate set of repeating occurrences. For more discussion, see the RFC5545 spec.
- AVAILABILITY If this event counts as busy time or is free time that can be scheduled over.
- GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY    Whether guests can modify the event.
- GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS Whether guests can invite other guests.
- GUESTS_CAN_SEE_GUESTS

None of them has anything to do with the user's ability to modify the event. so No it is not possible to do that using android's built in calendar.

Comment: Yes, this is property of event. 

But i can create a calendar not editable like facebook's event?